# Error with CakePHP returning a different table than the one specified

Tags: cakephp

So I am trying to get a find table into my elements view and I am doing that by making a helper function in my Tags controller.

```
<?php
class TagsController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'Tags';

    function gettags(){
        if (!empty($this->params['requested'])) {
            return $this->Tag->find('list', array('fields'=>'Tag.tag_name'));
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then in my view, I call

```
<? $tags = $this->requestAction('/tags/gettags'); debug($tags); ?>
```

However, it returns the error

> Warning (512): SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'Tag.tag_name' in 'field list' [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 684]
>   Query: SELECT `Tag`.`id`, `Tag`.`tag_name` FROM `users` AS `Tag`   WHERE 1 = 1

which means that it thinks my tags table is actually users. This doesn't happen in the Tags view. Anyone have any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? The tables aren't associated with either other or anything.

My Tag model is:

```
  <?php
class Tag extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Tag';

    var $hasMany = array(
        'BrandTag' => array(
            'className' => 'BrandTag',
            'foreignKey' => 'tag_id',
            'dependent' => true,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        ));

    }
?>
```

Comment: could you attach your Tag model file?

Comment: It's really not good practice to use `requestAction`. It kind of breaks the concept of MVC. You should really just set the results of your `gettags` function in the controller action that renders that view. Something like this: `$this->set('tags',$this->gettags());`

Comment: I would do that but there isn't a direct view attached to the elements  view in cakephp. So I just put the function inside the tags controller

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
$this->getModel('Tag')->find('list', array('fields'=>'Tag.tag_name');
```

As said you shouldn't be retrieving from a view like this, it's not good MVC practice.

If the Tag code will be retrieved by multiple controllers you should consider creating a component which these controllers can load as needed.

Comment: That's essentially what I'm doing when I call $this->Tag->... but strangely it is retrieving the User model instead of the Tag model

Answer (score 0):

Dao it may be worth going into you app/tmp/cache folder and deleting the files in the model folder. You may have cached a corrupt model.